# ISP Issues - TCP Out-of-Order

Tags: networking, openvpn, tcp, isp, udp

Accessing any webpage (basically any TCP connection), results in multiple retries before and long loading times before it loads a page with missing elements (reload might fix it). Google Chrome throws a ton of PROTOCOL_QUIC_Error or the like. Wireshark on port 80 shows a ton of TCP out of order error for every attempt before succeeding after a few tries.

[image: 1]

My temp solution:
I used an openvpn connection (over UDP) to overcome this, and it is smooth as before I started getting these errors.

Weirdly, even DNS lookups become extremely slow sometimes, but I know my ISP is DNS hijacking (for their login portal - even when using Google DNS). Any other UDP connection is basically flawless (League of Legends, Openvpn over UDP, Some video streaming services,etc.)

So, is this problem on the ISP's end? (maybe a bad firewall or something) or something to do with my router? (but never had this issue before and no change in my LAN config). I got the same issue by connecting directly with a PC with no router. How do I resolve this (or what causes such an issue?), other than using an external VPN connection?

Comment: If you haven't changed anything in your configuration, then the problem can't be with anything on your end. Call the ISP and ask them about it, meanwhile keep using the VPN.

Comment: I would, but my ISP never responds to any technical queries. They had horribly routing before, and they just replied with stock troubleshooting steps. It would help knowing if this occurs due to some common misconfiguration on their end, so that I could ask them something specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you, addressing two different problems.

As for DNS hijacking, you may want to try [dnscrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/). Besides their downloads (for Windows and Macs) you will find it in most Linux repos. It does something smart, *i.e.* it does not only change port (which is still subject to hijacking because packet identification may be made on the basis of the protocol, not of the port), but it **encrypts** DNS resolution requests, so that no firewall techniques can spot the request, not even those based on the protocol.

As for your major problem, you have already diagnosed it pretty much all by yourself: it lies upstream of you. I have sometimes seen this behavior at my University, and I know for a fact that it is connected with some problems in Cisco Class 6500 and 7600 routers (one more reason to suspect your ISP, I doubt you have forked the several thousand bucks necessary to acquire these industry-grade routers).

A guy in my dept. solved our problems by following [this guide](http://isamology.blogspot.com/2010/02/troubleshooting-fwsm-performance.html). Among many interesting things, it states:

> If this is TCP and you're getting poor performance consider enabling sysoption np completion-unit, this magic option is invoking special processing created to address scenarios in which FWSM was known to introduce out of order packets for TCP streams.

FWSM is the firewall blade for Cisco Class 6500 and 7600 routers.

There you go with your problem, diagnosis, and treatment. This is the best I can offer.

Comment: Wow, didn't know something like DNSCrypt existed. Lookups are much faster now (even compared to using OpenDNS/Google DNS directly), even though it looks like its using TCP - 443. That firewall stuff though, I highly doubt my Indian ISP is going to respond to that. It does seem like a major issue for firewall blade to have, regardless of bad configuration.  Then again, I know next to nothing about enterprise grade network hardware!

Comment: @smallet It is using 3 by default because generally, behind a firewall or a proxy, if they allow port 80 at all, then they always allow 3 (=https) as well.